# When debugging iAd goes green on a real device

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, iad

[image: The green Ad]

I am currently testing iAd on my iPhone 5s and everything works fine, beside of the fact that the Add is green. It pops up after some seconds and NSLog says Ad was received, but it's green in The simulator it works fine but on the iphone it's green. What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "green"? Does the Test Ad show up? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: iAd always comes up green in my Apps, on the simulator they are white.  I think this is the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: and have you ever submitted them to the App Store before? @Douglas

Comment: Just submitted the other day, but have not heard back just yet.  Although iAds work with the sample ads.

Comment: @Douglas yeah, mine works fine too… with the sample ads but it's green...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just read on the developers forum, that if you have your developer account on device set to highlight clipped banner, green means the view if fine not clipping, but red means that it is clipping.  So you are good to go!!!

EDIT#1 5/15/15

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865340/iad-adbannerview-appears-tinted-on-device#comment48127039_29865340) is another post I was involved with for some information pertaining to the tinted iAd banner!

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot! Oh could you maybe help e out with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085262/game-center-leader-board-error    Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  However, I never have used leader board.  Just reading up on that now.  Good luck!