# Game Center Leader Board Error

Tags: ios, game-center, sigabrt, leaderboard

I created this code for game center Leaderboards, and I always get `Thread 1 signal Sigabrt`. The NSLOG always says this :

```
2014-04-15 15:27:28.441 GameCenter[38225:60b] -[GKGameCenterViewController setLeaderboardDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb48dd90
2014-04-15 15:27:28.442 GameCenter[38225:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GKGameCenterViewController setLeaderboardDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb48dd90'
*** First throw call stack:
```

below a screenshot of the code i have for implementing the Leaderboard:[image]

Or/And please look at this question over here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068184/game-center-leaderboard-doesnt-work-in-xcode

Comment: Your first warning is the problem - your leaderboardController isn't a [GKLeaderboardViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), but is a [GKGameCenterViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKGameCenterViewController). GKGameCenterViewController doesn't have a leaderboardDelegate property.

Comment: @thegrinner and could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068184/game-center-leaderboard-doesnt-work-in-xcode? Thanks!