# iAd ADBannerView appears tinted on Device

Tags: ios, swift, device, iad, adbannerview

I'm getting a tinted `adBannerView` on the device, instead the normal `adBannerView` as it appears in the Simulator. Any ideas on this?[image]

Comment: I have read on the Apple developer's site, that green means that the frame is totally fine.  It would appear red if the frame was clipped at all.  However, I have seen apps (one of them mine) that the green tint stays even after you submit.  Would love to hear some feedback on this issue as well.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code showing how you're implementing your `ADBannerView` please.

Comment: there is no custom implementation of ADBannerView, it gets added with IB.

Comment: @Douglas do you have a link where Apple states this? I've never seen or experienced this issue myself.

Comment: @DanielStorm, I don't have the link any more, but I found it on the dev site. Try searching there.  In fact I just went back and can not find it at all.  Should have bookmarked it!

Comment: MrMatthias, after running a ton of tests, if you have clipping set on your phone it will be green on device, and regular on sim.  That is, if the iAd is not clipped!  So all is working well for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the device, go to Settings > Developer and disable the option "Highlight Clipped Banners" to remove the colored layer.

If enabled, the colors show you if the iAd banner view is clipped (red) or not (green).

Note that this setting is system-wide, and affects not only the development builds from your app, but also production builds from all other apps downloaded from the App Store. If you change this setting, you might have to restart the app to see changes.

This feature is also discussed in the WWDC 2013 Session 613: [iAd Integration and Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#613)

Comment: Theo, I know that answer, that is not what I am talking about.  I am talking about after you submit your app the ad is still green upon production.  I have seen this in one of my own apps and in several others.

Comment: @Douglas are you able to reproduce this on a device not setup for development with an application released in the App Store?

Comment: The coloring happens system-wide for all iAds. There's no difference if it's a development or production build. Thus, if the option is enabled, you will see all iAds colored, even for other developer's apps that you have downloaded from the App Store.

Comment: Theo, for my development test device, I have this setting on.  So in testing my app I will see the green, however, no one else's iAds are green when I play for instance some game with ads.  @Daniel Storm, since every device I have is set up for development, I have only noticed it on some of my devices.  Come to think of it, I have not witnessed it on any ones non-development device.

Comment: @Douglas I have just tested the setting on my development device again (running iOS 8.3) and, at least for me, iAds in other apps are colored as well. Apparently a restart of the app is needed sometimes. If you test it, make sure that the banners you see are really iAds (they have the small "iAd" label in the corner).

Comment: Theo, were is this setting now located in iOS 8.3.  It used to be in the developers section of the setting, but now I can't find it.  And by the way thank my cat, he stepped on my track pad and accepted your answer!!

Comment: @Douglas it is still located there for me on iOS 8.3. Settings>Developer>Highlight Clipped Banners

Comment: It's still there. Third entry in section "iAd Developer App Testing".

Comment: Thanks guys just found it!

Comment: Well, I just ran a billion tests and it is system-wide if my device is a dev device.  Thanks you both for helping me understand this a bit better!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I have added some details to my answer.